# MVC2 Areas and unit testing for routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas, unit-testing

I want to test my routes in unit tests. But Areas is not working in my unit tests.
Is it possible to test ASP.NET MVC 2 routes for Areas?

I am using this code

```
[SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.routes = new RouteCollection();
        MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(this.routes);
    }

    #endregion

    private RouteCollection routes;

    [Test]
    public void Should_Navigate_To_AdminUser_Controller_EditUser_Method()
    {
        HttpContextBase fackeCtx = CreateFackeContext("~/Admin/User/Edit/3");
        RouteData routeData = this.routes.GetRouteData(fackeCtx);
        Assert.IsNotNull(routeData,
                         "Route is not defined!");
        Assert.AreEqual("Edit",
                        routeData.Values["action"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("User",
                        routeData.Values["controller"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("3",
                        routeData.Values["id"]);
    }
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715940/unit-testing-asp-net-mvc-2-routes-with-areas-bails-out-on-arearegistration-regist

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [this post](http://flux88.com/blog/fluent-route-testing-in-asp-net-mvc/) which describes a nice and fluent framework for unit testing routes.